# c#, get and set for class property seems to have no effect

Tags: c#

so in my little c# console-program, i have i have this class, where I use get and set methods for my properties

```
class myClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public myClass(int ID, string value)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.value = value;

    }
}
```

however when i am im my main method, i am not able to access these two properties through the get-method, neither am i able to use set() on any of them, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have shown your class, but not the mistake in how you are calling it. Most likely you are creating a new instance, but we dont know, you havent shown us!

Comment: What does your code in main look like?

Comment: Also, class names and properties should start with an uppercase character so they don't get confused with fields and variables.

Comment: Please do not name a property or local `value`.  `value` is an unreserved keyword used in property setters; using it as a property name can be very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you don't need to invoke the getter or setter on a property:

```
var id = class.ID; // getter invoked automatically
```

Will automatically call the getter, and in your example, you're already using the setter in your constructor.

Comment: oh, so if I write objekt.ID its the exact same as using the get method?

Comment: @s3j80, exactly. These are called "auto-properties", if you look through the related questions in the sidebar, you can find more information about them, including how to supply your own custom getter and setter functions.